# Export a AVMutableVideoComposition using AVAssetWriter instead of AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have a `AVMutableVideoComposition` and I want to export it to a video file.

Unfortunately, `AVAssetExportSession` doesn't make the cut because I need fine control over the output video settings (bitrate, keyframes, ...)

How can I extract the images from `AVMutableVideoComposition` to feed them to an `AVAssetWriterInput` ?

So far I looked into `AVVideoCompositionRenderContext` and `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest` but both seems like dead ends since I can't find an API to render my `AVMutableComposition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an `AVAssetReader` to "read" the video frames from the `AVMutableVideoComposition`, and then hand them off to the `AVAssetWriterInput`. You would set up the asset reader with an `AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput`, setting the `videoComposition`, and possibly the `customVideoCompositor` if needed. The custom video compositor is where you can involve your own CIFilters and anything else you want.

Comment: Oh god, I don't know how I missed that. `AVMutableVideoComposition ` is a subclass of AVAsset !

Comment: Wait, I spoke too soon and mistook my `AVMutableComposition` with my `AVMutableVideoComposition`. While `AVMutableComposition` IS a subclass of `AVAsset`, `AVMutableVideoComposition` is not. Therefor no `AVAssetReader` can be used

Comment: Your comment is puzzling. Yes your Dec 12 comment mistakenly says AVMVC is a subclass of AVAsset, when it's really AV[Mutable]Composition that is, but that's not a problem... Everything I said is still valid and the correct solution. Is there something you still don't understand?

Comment: Sorry, my bad again. I re checked everything twice and it seems that you are right, altho I could'nt make an implementation yet.

Answer (score 0):

For now I assume this is impossible.

There is two workaround this limitation:

- Give up on `AVMutableVideoComposition` and use `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`.

  => This is what you should do if you just want to concat some videos.
- Make it two passes. Export the video once with `AVMutableVideoComposition` then read and write again.

  => Not optimal, I can get away with it because my videos are so small.
  => Much easier to write if you have transforms, `CIFilters`, and other complex operations.

Hope I'll get around with a cleaner solution next time: